# Find volume of solid by rotating about x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

R is the region bounded by the curves y=tan(x), y=cot(x), and the x-axis on the interval [0, pi/2]. Find the volume of the solid obtained by revolving R around x-axis.

I have tried everything, I am having trouble setting this problem up.

Comment: Outline: *Draw the curves.* By symmetry let's find the volume  up to $\pi/4$ and double. So we want to find $\int_0^{\pi/4}\pi\tan^2 x\,dx$. To integrate, use $\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by graphing to get an idea of your region.

[image]

From $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ our region is bounded by $y=\tan(x)$ and the $x$ axis. So the volume of just rotating that region will be:

$$\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2}(x)\space\text{d}x$$

The rest of our region from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is bounded by $y=\cot(x)$ so the volume of rotating just that region will be.

$$\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cot^{2}(x)\space\text{d}x$$

Find each integral than sum them up.

Comment: You forgot that we have your graph for times, from $0$ to $2\pi$!

Comment: @JanEerland  he specified his interval of concern is from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: But thanks you made be realize an error.

Comment: You're welcome! I meant $\frac{\pi}{2}$